# Django 1.1 template question

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a little stuck trying to get my head around a django template.

I have 2 objects, a cluster and a node

I would like a simple page that lists...

```
[Cluster 1]
[associated node 1]
[associated node 2]
[associated node 3]

[Cluster 2]
[associated node 4]
[associated node 5]
[associated node 6]
```

I've been using Django for about 2 days so if i've missed the point, please be gentle :)

Models -

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Cluster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views -

```
def DSAList(request):

    clusterlist = Cluster.objects.all()
    nodelist = Node.objects.all()

    t = loader.get_template('dsalist.html')
    v = Context({
                 'CLUSTERLIST' : clusterlist,
                 'NODELIST' : nodelist,
               })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(v))
```

Template -

```
<body>
    <TABLE>
    {% for cluster in CLUSTERLIST %}
        <tr>
         <TD>{{ cluster.name }}</TD>
                 {% for node in NODELIST %}
                     {% if node.cluster.id == cluster.id %}
                     <tr>
                       <TD>{{ node.name }}</TD>
                     </tr>
                     {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </TABLE>
</body>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can access the `Node` objects that are associated to a `Cluster` object via `cluster_obj.node_set` . See the documentation:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for cluster in CLUSTERLIST %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ cluster.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for node in cluster.node_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ node.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: if you want each node in it's own row below the cluster you need to edit your HTML too a bit.

[Following relationships "backward"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

[Many-to-one relationships](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_one/)

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you'd described what problem you were experiencing. But, you can't do this in Django 1.1:

```
{% if node.cluster.id == cluster.id %}
...
{% endif %}
```

You have to do

```
{% ifequal node.cluster.id cluster.id %}
...
{% endifequal %}
```

Of course, the right way to iterate through this sort of relationship is the way rebus has shown you.

Comment: snap, seeing it was unnecessary made me forgot to mention that it wasn't even supported in v1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the clusterlist to template and then:

```
{% for node in cluster.node_set.all %}
     <tr>
        <TD>{{ node.name }}</TD>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Your method should work as well with :

```
{% for node in NODELIST %}
    {% ifequal node.cluster.id cluster.id %}
        <tr>
          <TD>{{ node.name }}</TD>
          </tr>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```